Example of a global non-forking extension of a stationary type
I'm reading Bouscaren's Model Theory and Algebraic Geometry and I am having trouble understanding this example of a stationary type. Here $\mathfrak{C}$ is assumed to be a monster model, and a nonforking extension of $p \in S(A)$ is a type over some $B \supset A$ which contains $p$ and has the same Morley rank as $p$. A global extension is an extension of $p$ to $B = \mathfrak{C}$. 
I'm confused by the axiomatization of the global extension, particularly the part with $\neg x \overset{\circ}{=} c$ for all $c\in \mathfrak C$. This part is confusing me since then no $x \in \mathfrak C$ realizes the type with the axioms? However since the monster is assumed to be saturated I don't see how this could happen. Am I misinterpreting the $\overset{\circ}{=}$ incorrectly as an equals symbol, or is there something else here I am missing?

And what is the definition of saturated? (I know, but checking the definition may lead you to answer your own question.)

@AlexKruckman In this book $\kappa$-saturated means that for any family of (less than $\kappa$-many) definable subsets with finite intersection property, has nonempty intersection. However I don't see how the type as axiomatized would at all be consistent with the theory of $\mathfrak{C}$, since it's an algebraically closed field. So for any choice of $\alpha$ it should have some $\beta \in \mathfrak{C}$ satisfying $a\beta^2 = \alpha$. But the other axioms would forbid $\beta \in \mathfrak{C}$ would it not?

Recall that a model $M$ is $\kappa$-saturated if for any $A\subseteq M$ with $|A|<\kappa$, every type in $S(A)$ is realized in $M$. And "$M$ is saturated" means $M$ is $|M|$-saturated.
Note that a saturated model $M$ only realizes those types over parameter sets $A$ with $|A|<|M|$. In particular, it is not required to realize all the types in $S(M)$. Why? Well, if a type $p\in S(M)$ is realized in $M$, say by $a\in M$, then $p$ is a rather boring type: it is isolated by the formula $x = a$. As long as $M$ is infinite, there will always be types in $S(M)$ which are not realized in $M$, namely those that contain the formulas $\{x\neq m\mid m\in M\}$ (which are all the non-algebraic types). And typically we are much more interested in these types!
So that's what's going on in your example: the extensions of $D(x,y)$ to types in $S(\mathfrak{C})$ which are realized in $\mathfrak{C}$ correspond to actual $\mathfrak{C}$-valued points on the curve. They all have Morley rank $0$, since they are algebraic types. The nonforking extension of $D(x,y)$ to $S(\mathfrak{C})$, on the other hand, describes the type of a pair $(a,b)$ which "lives on" the curve but it not equal to any particular $\mathfrak{C}$-valued point on the curve. You can think of it as the type of a "generic point" on the curve, in the sense of algebraic geometry.
The fact that $\mathfrak{C}$ is algebraically closed is not really relevant here (although we need quantifier elimination to see that the axiomatization given in the book actually determines a complete type). The fact that the nonforking extension $p(x,y)$ is consistent with the theory of $\mathbb{C}$ is an easy compactness argument: a finite subset of $p$ just says $ax^2 = y$ and $x\neq c_i$ for finitely many elements $c_1,\dots,c_n\in \mathfrak{C}$, and this finite subset is realized by any of the infinitely many points on the curve whose $x$-coordinate is not one of the $c_i$.

The compactness argument makes sense, I think I was stuck on the idea that the monster should have all algebraically closed fields embedded in it, since it's defined to be class sized. The book also mentions earlier that the $\mathfrak{C}$ exists uniquely in naive set theory, but not in ZFC. So then would it be fair to call this an example where the use of naive set theory to choose a unique class monster breaks down?

@XavierbutwithaJ I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. One approach (but not the only approach!) to working with a monster model is to define it to be a proper class sized saturated model. In this case, it's true that every (set-sized) model can be elementarily embedded in it. If you take this approach, then the definition of "consistent type" over the monster model obviously can't be "realized in some (set-sized) elementary extension", since there are none. Instead, you can define a global type to be one that is finitely satisfiable in the monster model.

I guess that explains to me why saturated was defined as it was in this book. As for what I am asking is more akin to something I read in Marker (that I can't find right now) which states that $p \in S^M(A)$ iff there's an elementary extension $N$ of $M$ realizing $p$ (which i believe is the same as consistency). Is something like this never used or unnecessary when using the approach of a class sized monster model? Since in marker I believe it just fixes some large cardinal, rather than dealing with classes.

@XavierbutwithaJ It is sometimes convenient to realize global types in an elementary extension of the monster model, thereby moving to a larger monster model. In such situations, you may find it more convenient to work with a set-sized monster model (by assuming some set theoretic hypothesis or by working with a sufficiently saturated and strongly homogeneous model - or a so-called "special model" - instead of a saturated one). But usually there are ways around it at the expense of making the argument longer. I don't know of any proof where it is truly necessary to realize a global type.
